# How successfully can convnets detect NSFW images?

Tags: image-recognition, classification, convolutional-neural-networks

For example, search engine companies want to classify their image searches into 2 categories (which they already do that) such as: [NSFW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work) (nudity, porn, brutality) and safe to view pictures.

How can artificial neural networks achieve that, and at what success rate? Can they be easily mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2015 paper entitled "[Applying deep learning to classify pornographic images and videos](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08899.pdf)" applied various types of convnets for detecting pornography. The proposed architecture achieved **94.1% accuracy** on the NPDI dataset, which contains 800 videos (400 porn, 200 non-porn "easy" and 200 non-porn "difficult"). More traditional computer vision methods achieved 90.9% accuracy. The proposed architecture also performs very well regarding the ROC curve.

There does not seem to exist any works regarding the other aspects of NSFW yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem detecting NSFW has been around for over two decades.

---

This study from 2005 about [*finding naked people*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-61123-1_173), demonstrates a strategy for finding such images based on the color and texture properties to fetch an effective mask for skin regions attempting to group a human figure using geometric constraints on the human structure. This method demonstrated

> 60% precision and 52% recall on a test set of 138 uncontrolled images of naked people.

Here are a few figures from the study explaining the algorithm:

[image: Finding naked people via AI, neural network]

[image: Typical control images wrongly classified as containing naked people]

<sup>**The following post contains visualizations of nudity for scientific purposes (hover to display):**</sup>

> [image: Typical images correctly classified as containing naked people]

---

A more recent approach is using [convolutional networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conv-neural-network). This [study from 2014](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.683.4319)<sup>[PDF](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf)</sup> demonstrated impressive classification performance based on the ImageNet dataset. It's not clear '*[how and why](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1479/8)* they perform so well', however they can be used for classification of images with a very low error rate.

For further details, check: [What convolutional neural networks look at when they see nudity](http://blog.clarifai.com/what-convolutional-neural-networks-see-at-when-they-see-nudity/).

You will find the code example and the heatmap for how convnets see NSFW in the above link.